# Python sort a dictionary that has objects in it's values by alphabetical order of one of it's attributes

Tags: python, dictionary

so I'm making an agenda.

The attribute of agenda that manages the dictionary is : self.ContactList = {}

Inside this I have the telephone number as key for a contact (which is a class).

The Contact class has an attribute called telephone and other ones including the contact name.

I want a function that lists the contacts in the agenda, however I wanna list them by alphabetical order of the Contacts it contains.

Right now I'm using this to print the contacts (already have overriden the ____str____ of the contact class to allow this):

```
def listcontacts(self, agenda):
    print("Contact List\n")
    for tel, contact in agenda.ContactList.items():
        print(contact,"\n"*2)
```

How to sort self.ContactList by the contact's attribute "name"?

EDIT: The contact class is as follows

```
class Contact:
    def __init__(self, name, adress, zipcode, telephone):
        self.name = name
        self.adress = adress
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.telephone = telephone
    def __str__(self):
        return ( "Name: " + self.name + "\nAdress: " + self.adress + "\nZipCode: " + self.zipcode
                 + "\nTelephone: " + self.telephone)
```

Comment: sure but contact just has the initializer and the str

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have classes in your dictionary, you have objects. Objects are instances of classes.

Comment: @Lunaweaver You're right. My bad. (I'm really new at this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort a list, use the [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) function. If you want the sort to use an interesting ordering criterion, use the `key=` keyword:

```
for tel, contact in sorted(agenda.ContactList.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].name):
```